# Connecting to an external database in Joomla 4

Tags: mysql, joomla-4.x, database, jdatabase

Connecting to an external database in Joomla 3 is easy following [this documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database) and works like a charm. But JDatabaseDriver->getInstance method is deprecated in Joomla 4. What is the alternative method to do it in Joomla 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Joomla\Database\DatabaseFactory::getDriver()`](https://api.joomla.org/framework-2/classes/Joomla-Database-DatabaseFactory.html#method_getDriver):

```
$db = (new Joomla\Database\DatabaseFactory)->getDriver('mysqli', $options);
```