# Connecting to an external database in Joomla 4 - further problem

Tags: mysql, joomla-4.x, database, jdatabase

I have seen the earlier question on this subject and tried [the suggested code](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32404/12352):

```
$db = (new Joomla\Database\DatabaseFactory)->getDriver('mysqli', $options);
```

but get an error:

> An error has occurred with a eval'd field - please inform the web-site
> owner.    Debug: Caught exception on eval of *ElementName*: Database
> is not available in constructor in 5.0.

I also tried:

```
$db = DatabaseFactory::getDriver('mysqli', $options);
```

which gave the error:

> Non-static method Joomla\Database\DatabaseFactory::getDriver() cannot
> be called statically

How should this be done?

Comment: This looks like a Fabrik error.  The first piece of code works in normal J4.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have now persevered and found that the problem only occurs with eval’d code; elsewhere, Fabrik is fine with it, so I have a workaround. Fabrik4 is only in beta at the moment, so problems are not entirely unexpected.